# How to round down date to nearest day?

Tags: powerbi

Im trying to workaround the timezone problem when publishing a report to power bi server so the `today()` function works as expected.

So far, my calculation includes:

```
CasosDiaAnterior = 
CALCULATE(ContagiosDiariosCovid[CuentaCasos], 
COVID_ContagiosDiariosINS[fecha_reporte_web] = TODAY()-(5/24))
```

This should work but my issue is that `TODAY()-(5/24)` will return today's date with a different time than `00:00:00` and all my data has `00:00:00`, therefore the equality will never work

How can i round down `TODAY()-(5/24)` to the nearest day so it will always show the beginning of the day?

Answer (score 0):

`DATEVALUE` and `-(5/24)`, since im in timezone GMT-5, are doing the job.

```
CasosDiaAnterior = 
CALCULATE(ContagiosDiariosCovid[CuentaCasos], 
COVID_ContagiosDiariosINS[fecha_reporte_web] = DATEVALUE(today()-(5/24)))
```

Answer (score 0):

there should be no difference between TODAY and DATEVALUE(TODAY)

```
EVALUATE
    {
        ( "TODAY", TODAY () ),
        ( "DATEVALUE TODAY", DATEVALUE(TODAY ()) ),
        ( "UTCTODAY", UTCTODAY () ),
        ( "NOW", NOW () ),
        ( "UTC NOW", UTCNOW () )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: when uploading the report to powerbi in the cloud, there is a timezone difference that will affect my daily measurements. therefore, the need to use `-(5/24)`  (im in GMT-5) to overcome that. `DATEVALUE` will round down the resulting time to the nearest day (00:00:00).  I can confirm that my answer is working as expected.